# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre 'por mí mismo' y 'por mi cuenta'?

Tags: definiciones

¿Alguien puede explicar la diferencia entre las dos frases?

- por mí mismo
- por mi cuenta

¿'Por mi cuenta' significa solo puede estar con trabajo y 'por mí mismo' con acciones?

Comment: Hola Ana y bienvenida a [spanish.se]. No acabo de entender esto de *'Por mi cuenta' significa solo puede estar con trabajo*, ¿podrías darle a [edit] para clarificarlo? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Quizá se refiere a que se dice con frecuencia *trabaja por su cuenta* (es decir, trabaja sin relación de dependencia, sin un patrón o empleador). Pero sería bueno aclararlo.

Comment: Casi siempre uso "por mi cuenta," "por tu cuenta."  También a veces digo, "Hazlo tú mismo."  Con poca frecuencia digo, "Hazlo por ti mismo."

Answer (score 4):

*Por mi cuenta* significa "solo, sin ayuda de otras personas, de forma independiente", y también suele significar "sin prestar atención a otras personas, sin seguir a nadie". La connotación es de independencia de criterio, de no obediencia, de no cuidarse de lo que hagan otras personas. Por eso se usa mucho para hablar de trabajos o emprendimientos, pero no es el único caso en que puede usarse esta expresión.

*Por mí mismo* significa "solo, sin ayuda, sin intervención externa". Algo parecido a *por mi cuenta*, pero sin incluir la idea de criterio propio, sino más bien la de capacidad o iniciativa. También puede significa "en beneficio propio, para mí mismo", pero es menos frecuente.

Muchas veces los significados de estas dos frases son iguales pero se prefiere una o la otra según el contexto. Si hablo de trabajo independiente o de estar solo digo *trabajo por mi cuenta* o *estoy por mi cuenta*. Si hablamos de beneficio propio digo *(hago algo) por mí mismo*.

Algunos ejemplos:

- *Ella trabaja por su cuenta.* = "Ella es su propia jefa, es una trabajadora independiente."
- *Daré una fiesta por mi cuenta.* = "Daré una fiesta propia; no participaré en la fiesta de otras personas; organizaré mi propia fiesta."
- *Fui por mi cuenta a buscarla.* = "Fui a buscarla solo, sin preguntarle a otros su opinión; fui a buscarla sin pedir a nadie que me acompañara."

Con *por (mí, ti, si, etc.) mismo*:

- *Ayer logró levantarse de la cama por sí mismo.* = "Ayer pudo levantarse solo de la cama, sin ayuda."
- *Ella organizó la fiesta por sí misma.* = "Ella organizó la fiesta sola, sin ayuda, por iniciativa propia."
- *Hazlo por ti mismo y no por los demás.* = "Hazlo para tu propio beneficio, no para beneficio de otras personas."